# Magento only show current category in sidebar 'Shop By Category'

Tags: magento

I am looking for a possible way where I can only show the current sub categories withing a category on the side navigation on Magento e.g. when I click into a category I want to only display the sub categories of that category within the side navigations 'shop by category' and so on for the rest.

http://www.envirouk.com/index.php/lighting/led.html#

On the page above it is displaying all the categories and there sub categories where as I'm clicked on lighting I only want to show the sub categories for lighting.